# Annual percentage change dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series

I have a **time series** dataframe in R, lets call it `df`, that looks like this:

| Date | City_1 | City_2 | City_3 | ..... | City_n |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1980-01-01 | 1 | 4 | 6 | ... | 2 |
| 1980-01-02 | 2 | 7 | 6 | ... | 5 |
| 1980-01-03 | 3 | 7 | 1 | ... | 1 |
| 1980-01-04 | 8 | 1 | 8 | ... | 1 |
| 1980-01-05 | 4 | 3 | 5 | ... | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | 7 |
| 2020-08-20 | 3 | 1 | 8 | ... | 2 |
| 1980-08-21 | 7 | 8 | 3 | ... | 2 |
| 1980-08-22 | 8 | 6 | 5 | ... | 0 |
| 1980-08-23 | 9 | 8 | 2 | ... | 1 |

Here is a reproducible part of my data:

```
df <- structure(c(17.86, 18.65, 18.42, 19.21, 21.34, 11.35, 10.01, 
9.67, 10.12, 10.81, 20.77, 20.99, 20.88, 20.91, 20.5, 13.8, 13.63, 
13.6, 13.02, 13.87, 22.07, 22.78, 23.24, 23.33, 24.06), .Dim = c(5L, 
5L), class = c("xts", "zoo"), index = structure(c(315532800, 
315619200, 315705600, 315792000, 315878400), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), 
.Dimnames = list(NULL, c("Sao Paulo", "Mexico City", "Lima", "Bogota", 
"Rio de Janeiro")))
```

And I want to create a new dataframe that, in each city column, for each date, has the percentage change with respect to the same date the previous year, given by the following formula:

```
change = [x(t) -x(t-1)]/x(t)
```

To get a final dataframe, `df2` that will look like this:

| Date | City_1 | City_2 | City_3 | ..... | City_n |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1981-01-01 | a | j | s | ... | b |
| 1981-01-02 | b | k | t | ... | c |
| 1981-01-03 | c | l | u | ... | d |
| 1981-01-04 | d | m | v | ... | t |
| 1981-01-05 | e | n | w | ... | e |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | f |
| 2020-08-20 | f | o | x | ... | h |
| 1980-08-21 | g | p | y | ... | s |
| 1980-08-22 | h | q | z | ... | y |
| 1980-08-23 | i | r | a | ... | u |

Where all the letters are the percentage change of each day, respect last year.

I'm really new at R, but I think that I would need a function. Can you guys help me out?

Answer (score 0):

**--- Update ---**

**mock data**

```
df <- structure(c(17.86, 18.65, 18.42, 19.21, 21.34, 11.35, 10.01, 
              9.67, 10.12, 10.81, 20.77, 20.99, 20.88, 20.91, 20.5, 13.8, 13.63, 
              13.6, 13.02, 13.87, 22.07, 22.78, 23.24, 23.33, 24.06), .Dim = c(5L, 
                                                                               5L), class = c("xts", "zoo"), index = structure(c(315532800, 
                                                                                                                                 315619200, 315705600, 315792000, 315878400), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), 
            .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("Sao Paulo", "Mexico City", "Lima", "Bogota", 
                                     "Rio de Janeiro")))
```

**functions**

```
 findyear <- function(year2search,dates){
      idx <- which(year2search == dates)
      if (length(idx) == 0) idx <- NA
      return(idx)
    }

change <- function(x1, x2){
  return( (x1 - x2)/x1)
}
```

**Using base R**

```
 date <- as.Date(anytime::anytime(attributes(df)$index,asUTC = T))

year2search <- date - lubridate::years(1)
idx <- sapply(1:nrow(df), function(x) {findyear(year2search[x],date)})
res <- lapply(colnames(df), function(city) { print(city); df[, (which(colnames(df)==city))] <- change(df[, (which(colnames(df)==city))], df[, (which(colnames(df)==city))][idx])})
df_res <- matrix(unlist(res), ncol=ncol(df), nrow=nrow(df))
colnames(df_res) <- colnames(df)
```

**--Solution for data.frame--**

```
df <- data.frame(city1=c(17.86, 18.65, 18.42, 19.21, 21.34),
                 city2=c(11.35, 10.01,11.35, 10.01, 10.56),
                 city3=c(20.77, 20.99, 20.88, 20.91, 20.5),
                 date = seq(as.Date("1980/01/01"), as.Date("1984/01/01"), by="year"))
```

First solution using base R

```
year2search <- df$date - lubridate::years(1)
idx <- sapply(1:nrow(df), function(x) {findyear(year2search[x],df$date)})
res <- lapply(names(df)[1:3], function(city) { print(city); df[[city]] <- change(df[[city]], df[[city]][idx])})
df_res <- matrix(unlist(res), ncol=(ncol(df)-1), nrow=nrow(df))
colnames(df_res) <- names(df)[1:3]
```

Alternative solution using dplyr

```
df <- df %>% mutate(year2search = date - lubridate::years(1)) %>% 
  rowwise %>% mutate(idx = findyear(year2search,df$date))

for (city in names(df)[1:3]){
  df[[city]] <- change(df[[city]], df[[city]][df$idx])
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I get an error, using both dplyr & for loop and base R: Error in object[[i]] : subscript out of bounds. I think it is because there is no column name "date" in my original dataframe, instead, dates are the index of the rows. Can you help me?

Comment: The problem is that you are not working with a data.frame but with a matrix-like object. See my updated solution for a matrix (using your mock data). Note that because you have not any entry for a former year the result is all NA for all entries of the result.